# Datatype to Store and Retrieve HTML from sql server express 2012?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-5, sql-server-2012-express

I am using Jquery Text editor by using which I have to store and retrieve HTML **including images** from database, Is it possible to do or is it something silly to ask?? Just wondering if various CMS's are providing this functionality then it might be possible to put some hands on it. Forgive me if I am wrong. And by the way c# and Asp. Net MVC 5 would be the web application builder.

Comment: use varchar(max)  or nvarchar(max)